# Delegate usage with callback from unmanaged code

Tags: c#, delegates, unmanaged

This is from one of the C# books.  What I don't understand is that for this to be a callback, shouldn't the EnumWindow call to PrintWindow be made from user32.dll.  Maybe, I am not understanding delegates or callback properly.  Please help me to understand.

Callbacks from Unmanaged Code

The P/Invoke layer does its best to present a natural programming model on both sides of the boundary, mapping between relevant constructs where possible. Since C# can not only call out to C functions but also can be called back from the C functions (via function pointers), the P/Invoke layer maps unmanaged function pointers into the nearest equivalent in C#, which is delegates.

As an example, you can enumerate all top-level window handles with this method in User32.dll:

```
      BOOL EnumWindows (WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc, LPARAM lParam);

     WNDENUMPROC is a callback that gets fired with the handle of each window in sequence (or until the callback returns false). Here is its definition:
```

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc (HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam);

To use this, we declare a delegate with a matching signature, and then pass a delegate instance to the external method:

```
  using System;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

 class CallbackFun
{
    delegate bool EnumWindowsCallback (IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   static extern int EnumWindows (EnumWindowsCallback hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

   static bool PrintWindow (IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
   {
        Console.WriteLine (hWnd.ToInt64());
        return true;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        EnumWindows (PrintWindow, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
 }
```

Comment: For the callback, it is the **Hollywood principle** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_principle), which states "don't call us, we'll call you.", so you leave your phone number and they call you back :D Now the delegate is the how your "phone number" (method) should be formed.

Comment: Yes, the callback comes from user32.dll.  The pinvoke marshaller knows how to use Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate() to generate a pointer that it can pass EnumWindows().

Comment: Your question appears to be "shouldn't the EnumWindow call to PrintWindow be made from user32.dll?" What does that actually mean? That function is _in_ user32.dll, but the point of p/invoke (this example, and the feature in general) is to use unmanaged functions like that _from_ managed code. It wouldn't be much of an example of p/invoke if it just called an unmanaged function from unmanaged code.

Comment: @Peter- I am referring to :static void Main()
    {
        EnumWindows (PrintWindow, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
Here, EnumWindows is making a call to PrintWindow in main ().  For it to be considered a callback, the C# code will call the unmanaged code, which will call another C# function, triggering a callback. This was my understanding of a callback, which is why I got confused at the usage of EnumWindows(PrintWindows....) call in main() in CallBackFun class. I am trying to learn marshaling, delegates and callback at the same time, which may be confusing matters.

Comment: Yes, it probably is confusing things. :) Delegates and callbacks are natural topics to learn together, but it would be good to have mastered the concepts in managed code first, before trying to delve into the question of p/invoke. Unfortunately, it's not really clear in the question you posted what you're actually asking about; i.e. what your _question_ actually is.

Comment: @Peter- In static void Main() { EnumWindows (PrintWindow, IntPtr.Zero);  } PrintWindows is being passed as an argument inside Main() in CallBackFun.  As per the explanation listed above, shouldn't this call be in user32.dll to be classified as a callback (according to the definition of a callback)?  This is what is causing confusion for me. Please help to clarify.

Comment: "This call" being `EnumWindows(PrintWindow, IntPtr.Zero);`, right? Why do you think that the definition of "callback" requires that the caller of the function that calls the callback be in user32.dll? The word "callback" is equally applicable in any environment: .NET, native Windows API, and even other platforms having nothing to do with Windows, such as Linux, OS X, iOS, etc. I don't understand why it should be limited to such a specific scenario.

Comment: I thought that call back according to Wikipedia definition) means to call a function from a higher level to a lower level and then allowing the lower level library to make a call to another function in the higher-level libray, which gives the name callback.  So, by that definition, since "EnumWindows" is located in user32.dll, shouldn't the argument for "PrintWindows" be passed into EnumWindows in user32.dll to be genuinely called a callback? Please advise.